# New Kubernetes ConfigMap from file - plus sign?

Tags: kubernetes

Just ran the following command to create a new ConfigMap from a file:
`kubernetes create configmap foo --from-file=foo`

It gets created successfully.

Now when I run,
`kubernetes get configmaps foo -o yaml`

I see the following lines in the resulting output:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  foo: |+
    VAR1=value1
    VAR2=value2
```

**What does the plus sign in this line mean?**
`foo: |+`

It doesn't appear in any of my other ConfigMaps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`|+` is not kubernetes specific, it's part of yaml.

From http://lzone.de/cheat-sheet/YAML:

```
# + indicator (keep extra newlines after block)
content: |+
   Arbitrary free text with two newlines after


foo: ...
```